# Can't detect components in vue component with v-pre

Tags: vue.js, vue-devtools

I want to create nested element mounted vue.
However, vue-devtools can't detect components in vue component with v-pre. See desired code below:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <header></header>

    <main id="main" v-pre>
      something contents... <!-- NOT detected by vue-devtools -->
    </main>

    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Attached JavaScript:

```
...

// About layouts
new Vue({
  el: '#id',
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer
  }
});

// About main contents
new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  components: {
    ...
  }
});

...
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Why are you creating two Vue instances manually with `new`? Why not just use a single instance?

Comment: Naturally, it should be single instance. But in this case, these codes described in different files to manage it like rails views.